Doob's Stopping theorem for Wald equation for second moment of random sum
Assume $X=(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a iid sequence of square integrable random variables with $\mathbb E[X_i]=0$. Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_i.$ A new process
$$V_n=S_n^2-n\mathbb E[X_1^2].$$
This defines a martingale with respect to the canonical filtration of the $X_i$.
Now let $T$ be a $\mathcal L^1$ stopping time for the same filtration. Then the stopping theorem of Doob would imply
$$0=\mathbb E[V_1]=\mathbb E[V_T]=\mathbb E[S_T^2]-\mathbb E[T]\mathbb E[X_1^2].$$
However, the stopping theorem demands for either $|V_n|\leq K$ a.s. for all $n$, or $|V_{n+1}-V_n|\leq K$ a.s. for all $n$, for some constant $K$.
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb E[|V_{n+1}-V_n|| \mathcal F_n]
        &=\mathbb E\Big[\big|(S_n+X_{n+1})^2-(n+1)\mathbb E[X_1^2]-S_n^2+n\mathbb E[X_1^2]\big|\,|\mathcal F_n\Big]\\
        &=\mathbb E\Big[\big|2\,S_nX_{n+1}+X_{n+1}^2-\mathbb E[X_1^2]\big|\,|\mathcal F_n\Big]\\
        &\leq 2\,|S_n|\mathbb E[|X_1|]+2\,\mathbb E[X_1^2].\end{align*}$$
This is not bounded uniformly.
Trying
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\big[|V_{n+1}|\,|\mathcal F_n\big]
&\leq\mathbb E[S_{n+1}^2|\mathcal F_n]+(n+1)\,\mathbb E[X_1^2]\\
&=\mathbb E[S_{n}^2+2S_{n}X_{n}+X_n^2|\mathcal F_n]+n\,\mathbb E[X_1^2]\\
&=S_n^2+(n+1)\,\mathbb E[X_1].
\end{align*}$$
Also not bounded.
Do i need to assume that $T$ is bounded, or does work somehow without that assumption?
In comparison, what exactly goes wrong applying Eve's law?
$$
\begin{align*}
  Var[S_T]
&=\mathbb E[Var[S_T|T]]+Var[\mathbb E[S_T|T]]\\
&=\mathbb E[T\,Var[X_1]]+Var[T\,\mathbb E[X_1]]\\
&=\mathbb E[T]Var[X_1]
\end{align*}
$$

It seems, the answer is uniform integrability of $(X_n)_n$. I will edit as soon as I have more info.

As an aside, your Eve's Law approach could work, but it's not the case that $\Bbb E[S_T|T] =0$. For example, it $T$ is the first time the simple symmetric random walk hits ${-1,100}$, one expects $S_T$ to be 100 with high probability when $T$ is large. One can use known formulas to check that for this stopping time $T$, $\Bbb E[S_T\cdot z^T]$ is not identically $0$ for $0<z<1$, as it would be were $\Bbb E[S_T\mid T]=0$.

Where am i using $\mathbb E[S_T|T]=0$?

In concluding that $\Bbb E[S_T\mid T] = T\Bbb E[X_1]$.

I do not see what you are talking about: $\mathbb E[S_T|T=n]=\mathbb E[S_n]=n,\mathbb E[X_1]=0$ for every n. This is because $\mathbb E[X_i]=0$ is an assumption.

While it is true that $\Bbb E[S_T\mid T=n]=\Bbb E[S_n\mid T=n]$, it may be that  $\Bbb E[S_n\mid T=n]$ is different from $n\Bbb E[X_1]$.
Suppose, for example, that $(S_n)$ is the simple symmetric random walk; that is $\Bbb P[X_k=1]=\Bbb P[X_k=-1]=1/2$ for each $k$. Let $T$ be the stopping time equal to $1$ if $S_1=1$ and to $2$ otherwise. Then $\Bbb E[S_1\mid T=1]=1$ but $1\cdot\Bbb E[X_1] =1\cdot 0=0$.

I see. Classic error then. Thank you for elucidating this aspect!
